# Dapper Query One To Many Relation

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, dapper

I am facing a problem to mapping the query into a model.

**Each TaxId has many Merchants, but when I map using Dapper the property Merchants is empty. The model has one TaxId, a list of Merchants, and one card brand.**

**Model**

```
public class LeadModel
{
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Merchants { get; set; }
    public string CardBrand { get; set; }
}
```

**Query**

```
SELECT "RegistrationNumber" as "TaxId"
     , jsonb_agg("MerchantReference") as "Merchant"
     , 'X' as "CardBrand"
  FROM "Merchant" 
 WHERE "MerchantId" in...
```

**Database Query**

| TaxId | Merchant | CardBrand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 77777777777777 | 101010101000000 | X |
| 12345678901234 | 202020202000000 | X |
| 77777777777777 | 303030303000000 | X |
| 77777777777777 | 404040404000000 | X |
| 12345678901234 | 505050505000000 | X |

**Code**

```
var leadModels = _dbConnection.Query<string, List<string>, LeadModel>(sql, (taxId, merchants) =>
{
    LeadModel leadModel = new LeadModel();

    leadModel.TaxId = taxId;
    leadModel.Merchants = merchants;
    leadModel.CardBrand = cardBrand;

    return leadModel;

 }, dynamicParameters, splitOn: "cardBrand")
    .ToList();
```

**Current Result**

[image]

References: https://dapper-tutorial.net/query#example-query-multi-mapping-one-to-many

Comment: Why do you expect Merchants to be passed as a List(Of Strings)? Dapper will give you one record at time and it is up to you to put in the List. The example you posted does exactly this using a Dictionary to store the main record and the record returned from the joined table. You can do the same with the strings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main changes were:

- Query parameters
- Deserialization from a list of strings into the Merchants property (`IEnumerable<string>`)
- Add in the `splitOn` the columns

Result:

```
var leadModels = _dbConnection.Query<string, string, string, LeadModel>(sql, (taxId, merchant, cardBrand) =>
{
    LeadModel leadModel = new LeadModel();

    leadModel.TaxId = taxId;
    leadModel.Merchants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(merchant);
    leadModel.CardBrand = cardBrand;

    return leadModel;

}, dynamicParameters, splitOn: "TaxId,Merchant,CardBrand")
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Nowhere in your question is there any indication that the Merchants are stored in a Json list. This might be a solution to your problem, but it's not an answer to your question.

Comment: The return from the database is in json, the Merchant property. The problem was how to put the list of merchants from the database into the Merchant (IEnumerable<string>)